# Flutter BLoC Not Updating UI When Data in Stream Changes

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, stream, bloc

I'm working on a Flutter app that uses the BLoC pattern for state management, and I'm having trouble getting my UI to update when the data in a stream changes. Specifically, I have a SocketBloc responsible for handling socket communication, and I want to reflect changes in the socket data in my UI. However, despite my best efforts, the UI doesn't update when new data arrives via the socket.

Here's an overview of my code:

```
// [Include relevant imports]

class SocketBloc extends Bloc<SocketEvent, SocketState> {
  // [Constructor and initialization]

  final SocketRepo _socketRepository;
  final _socketResponse = StreamController<String>();
  Stream<String> get getResponse => _socketResponse.stream;

  void countNotification() {
    // [_socketRepository.emit] sends a socket request
    _socketRepository.emit('get-unread-notification-count');

    _socketRepository.on('unread_notification_count', (data) {
      _socketResponse.sink.add(data.toString());
     
    });
  }

  dispose() {
    _socketResponse.close();
  }
}
```

In my UI, I have used **StreamBuilder** to listen to changes in SocketState, but it doesn't seem to rebuild when the socket data changes. I've also confirmed that the socket events are working correctly, and data is being received in the _socketResponse stream.

```
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BlocProvider.of<SocketBloc>(context).add(const SocketGetNotification());
  }
 ....
 StreamBuilder(
            stream: BlocProvider.of<SocketBloc>(context).getResponse,
            builder: (
              ctx,
              snapshot,
            ) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
              } else {
                return Text("Waiting");
              }
         }),
```

Comment: would be great if u can create a gist, 
from the first look this code can be really improved alot, the current way u have written we basically dont even need bloc as per ur implementation (since u have not utilised it correctly), ill provide a slightly different impl than the one u have used which is going to utlise bloc properly

Comment: u would need to revisit your implementation for a usage something similar to this  https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z61k066w61l0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/socket_bloc.dart:0-48, let me know if this helps

Comment: Typically a Bloc triggers a UI update by emitting an updated State.  The Bloc could listen to your stream and then add an event to itself when it hears a new value.  Then when processing that event, the bloc could call emit.

Comment: @Afzal thanks for your help but still UI is not updating.  This is how I implemented in my bloc code: https://tapshare.xyz/code/64f59358a0c350d96eb90568 . For the UI part, I followed a similar pattern to yours. Is the any mistake in the implementation with the socket or any? Please help me.

Comment: hey could u check if ur socket correctly connects to upstream and sends data back ?

Comment: @Afzal The first time, it successfully fetches the data, but it doesn't work on the second try. When I tried it without using BLoC, it worked fine.

Comment: whats does second try here refers to? cannot understand the concept here

Comment: can u revamp ur bloc similar to what i have done here? 
https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z61k066w61l0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/socket_bloc.dart:0-48, to better help u, u would need to provide a proper reproduction sample, if u see the link i have share i mocked the socket impl and it works fine, i think u can try revamping ur bloc first

Comment: @Afzal here is a sample how I implemented: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zn2206v7n230?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/socket_repo.dart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255165/discussion-between-yunesh-shrestha-and-afzal).